# Accessing the QTabBar instance

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

How can I get access to the [QTabBar](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtabbar.html) of a [QTabWidget](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html)?

The only solution I've found is to subclass `QTabWidget` and override the protected `QTabWidget::getTabBar()` as public. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: That's what I did in one of my applications. By the idea posted bellow looks cool enough for me to kill one more class.

Comment: Why do you need to access to the TabBar? This may help us to direct you to a solution which corresponds to your problem.

Comment: I wan't to know QTabBar height at runtime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tabBar->findChild<QTabBar *>(QLatin1String("qt_tabwidget_tabbar"));
```

Comment: It's looks like Qt has direct way to violating encapsulations principles, but acceptable in my case :) +1, if will no another answers I will accept this answer.

Comment: the only problem is...what if Qt decides to change the name of the tabbar object?

Comment: AFAIK, names were defining in QtDesigner by developer (in case, when you create gui with designer)...

Comment: @vnm The tab bar widget is not accessible via the designer, and the object name is in the Qt source code.

Comment: Thanks for this, I used it to remove the "close tab" button of only certain tabs, using:
`QTabBar *tabBar = tabWidget->findChild<QTabBar *>(QLatin1String("qt_tabwidget_tabbar"));
tabBar->setTabButton(tabIndex, QTabBar::RightSide, 0);
`

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned, subclassing is the proper solution since it is protected. Something like this:

```
class TabWidget : public QTabWidget {
public:
    TabWidget(QWidget *p = 0) : QTabWidget(p){}

public:
    QTabBar *tabBar() const { return QTabWidget::tabBar(); }
};
```

You can tell designer to "promote" your QTabWiget to a TabWidget then you will have an accessible `tabBar()` function.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do to the tab bar?

May not help, but with [stylesheets](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar) you can customise QTabWidget sub-controls ::tab and ::tab-bar.

Comment: Trying to use stylesheets to customize `QTabWidget::tab-bar`, for example to set `border-bottom: 0px;` does not work.